# Puppeteer don't return all requests from a particular website

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I have the following code that extract all request from a particular website (Get all images, css, scripts, fonts...)

```
var totalRequests = 0;

    puppeteer.launch().then(async browser => {
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.setRequestInterception(true);
        page.on('request', interceptedRequest => {
            interceptedRequest.continue();
        });
        page.on('response', response => {
            totalRequests = totalRequests + 1;
            console.log('Url: ' + response.url());
        });
        await page.goto('https://stackoverflow.com');
        await browser.close().then(() => {
            res.send('Requests: ' + totalRequests);
        });
```

Great, in console I can see all the Url's from **stackoverflow.com** (Css Files, Image Files, Font Files and Javascript Files) and a total files that was requested (In this case I see 31 requests), but for some reason I ended up noting that this code does not return all page requests.

If we go to Google Chrome, press F12, go to network section and reload the page (consider that you are on the url **https://stackoverflow.com**), we will see a total of 39-40 requests files.

The problem is that my code is only returning 30 to 31 requests, and in console I can't see all links that was shown like on Chrome. What might be happening ? And what could I do to return all requests like as shown in Google Chrome?

Comment: Which version of Puppeteer are you using? This issue seems to [be resolved](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/2970). Anyway, I remember a problem like this was asked here "recently" but I can't find it at the moment

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Main issue

For `stackoverflow.com` the number of loaded resources depends on the size of your browser window. If your viewport allows it, stackoverflow will show you ads (on the right sidebar). But the corresponding resources (JavaScript, images, etc.) will only be loaded if the size of your viewport is wide enough. Try this out yourself by reducing the size of your window until the right sidebar is hidden and then reload the page. The DevTools will show you a different number of loaded resources.

**Example code**

The following example shows how to simulate a larger browser window by setting the `defaultViewport` property. Note, that I'm fully using *async/await* syntax in this example and I removed the `page.setRequestInterception` call as the `response` event will also be triggered without it (you only need to use it if you really want to modify the request or response).

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ // headless: false, devtools: true,
        defaultViewport: { width: 1600, height: 800 }
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    var totalRequests = 0;
    page.on('response', () => {
        totalRequests = totalRequests + 1;
    });

    await page.goto('https://stackoverflow.com');
    console.log(totalRequests);

    await browser.close();
})();
```

This returns `30` for me, which is still not the number we are expecting (~40).

#### Waiting until all resources are loaded

There is another problem with your code. Let's open the DevTools to see what is happening. If you look at the waterfall diagram in your network tab, it looks like this:

[image: Waterfall Diagram in Chrom DevTools]

See that red line? This is the load event. By default [`page.goto`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.14.0/docs/api.md#pagegotourl-options) waits for this event. But in our case there are actually a few files that are being loaded after the event is fired (the files to the right of the red line). To also wait for these resources to load, we can use one of the options of the `page.goto` function. Using `waitUntil: 'networkidle0'` the script will wait until there is no more network activity.

So if you switch out the `page.goto` line from the top with this line, you should see the expected number of requests:

```js
await page.goto('https://stackoverflow.com', { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });
```

When using this setting, the code from above returned `39` for me, which is what you are expecting.

Comment: Great! Best Answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the viewPort issue, I recommend reloading the page. My use case is to get all Google analytics requests, but it doesn't always return on the first visit. To reload:

```
await page.reload({ waitUntil: 'networkidle2' })
```